# Contacts entering my journey but the interaction (email message) is not firing

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I need help troubleshooting why my automation is running as expected and I see contacts being injected into my journey, but my journey email message is not being sent. I am seeing contacts appropriately load into my sendable data extension, but the journey won't fire.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you see any errors in the journey history for send activity? 
Quite possible that the email is not going out because of errors with rendering or personalization.

Go to your email and do a send preview with the entry source DE of this journey and see if the email is correctly previewed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @Praveen. It was an issue with the default email address in the journey's settings.

Comment: Cool. Glad you found the solution J.Smith.